# mingw/include/c++/cstdlib: stdlib.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, mingw, fedora

I am trying to cross-compile [OpenImageIO](https://github.com/OpenImageIO/oiio/tree/release) for 64-bit Windows on Fedora 26 using MinGW. After using `yum` to retrieve the mingw versions of the dependencies, I ran `mingw64-cmake` followed by `make`. However, right away I receive a compile error about `stdlib.h` not being found.

```
[  0%] Built target CopyFiles
[  0%] Building CXX object src/libutil/CMakeFiles/OpenImageIO_Util.dir/argparse.cpp.obj
In file included from .../oiio/src/libutil/argparse.cpp:36:0:
/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/c++/cstdlib:75:15: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
#include_next <stdlib.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I have confirmed that `stdlib.h` is found at least in `/usr/include/` and in `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/c++/` where the file giving the compiler error also is located.

Why do I still receive the error `stdlib.h: No such file or directory`?

**Update:**
I did additional research and learned the following: `The preprocessor directive #include_next behaves like the #include directive, except that it specifically excludes the directory of the including file from the paths to be searched for the named file.`

This would explain why `cstdlib` does not find `stdlib.h` from the same folder. But `cstdlib` is part of MinGW and not any part of the code I am trying to compile. So I still have no idea what is wrong here or how to fix this error.

**Edit**: Here is the compiler version info in case it is of any use: https://pastebin.com/PZiXS2fg. This is a fresh install so there shouldn't be anything unusual there, though.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which `g++` version is included with your `mingw64`?

Comment: @TriskalJM gcc version 7.1.0 20170502 (Fedora MinGW 7.1.0-1.fc26)

Comment: Isn't there a `stdlib.h` in your `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/` which would be found by `#include_next`?

Comment: @ssbssa there is a `stdlib.h` in the `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/c++` folder, but not in the `include` folder. The `c++` folder is also where it should be looking for it.

Comment: That's not what my `cstdlib` says:
`// Need to ensure this finds the C library's <stdlib.h> not a libstdc++
// wrapper that might already be installed later in the include search path.
#define _GLIBCXX_INCLUDE_NEXT_C_HEADERS
#include_next <stdlib.h>`
And the C library's `<stdlib.h>` should definitely *not* be in the `c++` folder.

Comment: @ssbssa My bad, there IS a `stdlib.h` also in the `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include` folder. The other `stdlib.h` in `c++` folder is a `C++ compatibility header` according to the comment in the file. Regardless, it seems that neither file is found by the `#include_next`.

Comment: Sounds bad. Does it find it if you compile just `#include <cstdlib>` with `g++ -c`, or just `#include <stdlib.h>` with `gcc -c`?

Comment: @ssbssa Both of those one-liners seem to compile.

Comment: Can you add the output of `make VERBOSE=1`, so we will know the full command line options used to compile argparse.cpp?

Comment: @ssbssa [`make VERBOSE=1` output here](https://pastebin.com/mJz2xTN7). From that I just found out that the contents of [CMakeFiles/OpenImageIO_Util.dir/includes_CXX.rsp](https://pastebin.com/Fne5HVEs) might be related to the issue - it seems to contain `-isystem /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include` which contains a copy of `stdlib.h`. Removing this statement gives me [a completely different error](https://pastebin.com/xsAu2zvs) instead. I am looking into whether this is now a completely independent problem.

Comment: I wonder why those `-isystem` are there at all (both), since those directories should be found automatically by the compiler.

Comment: @ssbsa I wonder the same. However, removing the `-isystem` from the `CMakeFile` seems to fix the problem. The new error I got afterwards I simply worked around by eliminating the unnecessary Win32-specific defines from `oiio/src/include/OpenImageIO/missing_math.h`. Now there are no more errors and it seems to compile. Thanks for the hints! Still need to figure out where that `-isystem` is coming from and how to fix that without having to directly edit CMakeFiles after cmake and this could be turned into an answer.

Answer (score 5):

I solved it, i can compile again.

The solution (for me) is add to path the variable `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` and set it to the MinGW c++ include directory, for me: `C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++`.

I hope it works for you too.

Comment: Works for me! Also have to restart the computer.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `#include_next` appears to cause lots of issues based on my Googling. Try directly including `stdlib.h` using the following syntax:

```
-isystem /usr/x86_64-w64-ming32/sys-root/mingw/include/c++
```

This syntax was added in `gcc` 6.0 to solve issues with third-party libraries. See [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Wrapper-Headers.html#Wrapper-Headers) for the approach and reasoning.

*Edit:* Changed answer to reflect new information about gcc wrapper_headers and `#include_next`

Comment: Those are GCC configure flags. Are you suggesting to recompile GCC?

Comment: I tried running:
`mingw64-cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS='--with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/c++ --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs'`
But I receive:
`unrecognized command line option '--with-gxx-include...'`

Comment: @TriskalJM I added the `-isystem /usr/x86_64-w64-ming32/sys-root/mingw/include/c++ flag`, confirmed with `make -n` that g++ is indeed being run with the flag, and confirmed that `stdlib.h` is in that directory. Still get the exact same error, though.

Comment: You mentioned two directories that contain a version of `stdlib.h`. Which version is g++ pulling in?

Comment: @TriskalJM The g++ arguments are as follows: pastebin.com/LHcqqAkr.
Full g++ version info here https://pastebin.com/PZiXS2fg.
I have the default `--includedir=/usr/include` which is where the other version of `stdlib.h` is. I have a fresh installation of Fedora 26 and newest version of the packages, haven't done any changes which should cause problems.

Comment: It might be the search order. Does `/usr/include` get included first, or does `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/c++/`?

Comment: @TriskalJM I am unsure. As can be seen in the pastebin link above, even without the `-isystem` flag these directories are already included in the g++ configuration with `--includedir` and `with-gxx-include-dir` with the flags in this order. Whether they actually get included in this order I couldn't figure out from the documention.